# How do you get HPC to acknowledge that you have 100% code coverage with guards in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, code-coverage

I'm trying to get (and prove) 100% test coverage for some code I'm writing in Haskell using HPC. However if I write something like this:

```
fac n | n > 0 = n * (fac (n - 1))
      | otherwise = 1
```

Then the second expression of the guard statement has always True tagged to it. What is the easiest way to overcome this in the general case?

edit:
Just to clarify. This code:

```
fac n = if n > 0 then n * (fac (n - 1))
        else 1
```

Works fine with HPC, (running it gives 100% code coverage).

I'm basically suffering from this problem: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3175

Comment: What do you mean by overcome?  Your function is a total function(it is defined for all inputs.)  You reach 100% code coverage on this function when you try it with a positive number and a negative number.

Comment: I mean if write a set of unit tests for it then HPC won't ever tell you it has 100% code coverage.

Comment: Can't you replace `otherwise` with cases for equality and less than? Since the (numeric) input type T has a total order, for all n, m in T, either n < m, n = m, or n > m. Just define cases for each.

Comment: @danportin, that doesn't work either.

Comment: This is clearly a bug in HPC.  Report it. :-)

Comment: @luqui, See ticket #3175, (link above).

Comment: I think this is more 'how HPC reports' than anything else. Does the `hpc markup` command generate what you would expect?

Comment: @ScottWest, no, `hpc markup` renders the otherwise expression in green.

Comment: I would think that it is supposed to be green, everytime it is encountered, it is true, likewise with `n <= 0`. I don't understand why green is a problem, all of your expressions are covered.

Comment: Why does this matter?  The point is to ensure that the code is well-tested, which you have acheived.  If you are dealing with a brain-dead coding standard that requires "100%" then attach a memo to the coverage report explaining why HPC doesn't report 100% and showing that you have accounted for all the uncovered cases or bits of code.

Comment: Bear in mind that "otherwise" is a value not a keyword.  Its defined in the prelude as "otherwise = True".  So being green is the Right Thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no issue. If an expression is marked as always true, that does not mean that you have less than 100% coverage. As an example, I just wrote a small executable based on fac, then ran hpc on it and hpc report on the resulting tix file.

Here's the source:

```
fac n | n > 0 = n * (fac (n - 1))
      | n == 0 = 1
      | otherwise = 125 -- An arbitrary value. This of couse is demo code, and not actually a factorial.

main = print (fac 12) >> print (fac (negate 100))
```

and here's the result:

```
100% expressions used (23/23)
 66% boolean coverage (2/3)
      66% guards (2/3), 1 always True
     100% 'if' conditions (0/0)
     100% qualifiers (0/0)
100% alternatives used (3/3)
100% local declarations used (0/0)
100% top-level declarations used (2/2)
```

The key thing is 100% expressions used, and 100% alternative used, 100% top-level declarations used. The fact that you have 66% boolean coverage is irrelevant. That's why if you run hpc markup and look at the resulting hpc_index file, it reports top level, alternative, and expressions, but *not* boolean coverage.

Comment: Can I suggest you change `125` to `undefined`? (assuming 125 is arbitrary)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the guard syntax with lots of "if then else" expressions. I don't know of any better ways to do it.